# Ideal way of using thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a web application, I am fetching some ids from elastic search. After fetching the ids I divide them into batches of 1000 each and query the database for more information of those ids. I have to query 4 different tables of the database for fetching all the information of a particular id that I want. To optimize it I used a fixed thread pool of size 10 having singleton object to process the different batches of 1000 each. Then I made a fixed thread pool of size 4 from each of these threads to query the 4 tables parallely. Now since it is a web application it will receive request parallely from different users creating a bottleneck due to the pool size because there is a single pool for all request(of size 10), so I just want to know what should be the ideal way of parallelizing the tasks here.

Comment: What is your actual problem? Is this pool of size 10 that you mention in the beginning the same pool as the one you mention last? Why do you created new thread pools from each thread? That seems to defeat the purpose of having a thread pool in the first place.

Comment: Yes the two thread pools are the same. Actually the first pool implements Callable because I want a custom object used in my project to be returned by it. The second thread pool (of size 4) just fetches the different attributes of the objects and updates it.

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question - you haven't provided specific details to look at your problem, and you're also not presenting a concrete question (asking for an "ideal way" without stating what ideal means to you is hard to answer). I'm confused by your comment that your pool implements Callable - that's not something that thread pools do. Maybe you should restate your question more clearly and focus on something smaller and concrete to ask for.